# How can I merge pdf files so that each file begins on an odd page number?

Tags: pdf, merge

I need to merge a few dozed pdfs, and i want all of the input pdfs to start on an odd page in the output pdf.

Example: `A.pdf` has 3 pages, `B.pdf` has 4 pages.  I *don't want* my output to have 7 pages. What I want is an 8-page pdf in which pages 1-3 are from `A.pdf`, page 4 is empty, and pages 5-8 are from `B.pdf`. How can I do this?

I know about pdftk, but I didn't find such an option in the man page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [pypdf library](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) makes this sort of things easy if you're willing to write a bit of Python. Save the code below in a script called `pdf-cat-even` (or whatever you like), make it executable (`chmod +x pdf-cat-even`), and run it with output redirected to a file `./pdf-cat-even a.pdf b.pdf >concatenated.pdf` — current versions of pypdf don't support writing to a pipe).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import copy, sys
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader
output = PdfWriter()
output_page_number = 0
alignment = 2           # to align on even pages
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    # This code is executed for every file in turn
    input = PdfReader(filename)
    for p in input.pages:
        # This code is executed for every input page in turn
        output.add_page(p)
        output_page_number += 1
    while output_page_number % alignment != 0:
        output.add_blank_page()
        output_page_number += 1
output.write(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! As i prefer to read the names of the pdfs from a file, i've modified your code slightly and posted it as a [separate answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66543/32950).

Comment: @JanekWarchol If your file names don't contain shell special characters such as whitespace: `./pdf-cat-even $(cat list-of-file-names.txt) >concatenated.pdf`

Comment: Unfortunately they do contain whitespaces.  But thanks nevertheless - i didn't realize it could be done this way.

Comment: @JanekWarchol Then you can use `<list-of-file-names.txt tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ./pdf-cat-even >concatenated.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to produce a pdf file with an empty page. You can do this easily with a lot of programs (LibreOffice/OpenOffice, inkscape, (La)TeX, scribus, etc.)

Then just include this empty page where needed:

```
pdftk A.pdf empty_page.pdf B.pdf output result.pdf
```

If you want to do this automatically with a script, you can 
use e.g. `pdftk file.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | egrep -o '[0-9]*'` to extract the page count.

Comment: This feels like a bit of a hack. Though if it works, it works I suppose.

Comment: This approach almost worked for me: i wrote a script that produced a list of pdfs with epmtyPage.pdf added where necessary, but i couldn't get pdftk to correctly parse this list if the filenames contained spaces.  I've tried changing IFS value, using quotation marks but to no avail - maybe it's pdftk's fault. Anyway, [the answer using pypdf](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66455/32950) worked for me.

Comment: @JanekWarchol Which version of pdftk did you use? At least pdftk 1.44 and newer seems to support whitespaces in filenames.

Comment: @jofel `pdftk --version` returns pdftk 1.44.  I remember that my more-bash-savvy friends spent at least 15 minutes trying different things to get this work and gave up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use LaTeX to do this (though I'm aware it's probably not what you want). Something like the following should work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{A}
\cleardoublepage % Make sure we clear to an odd page
\includepdf[pages=-]{B} % This inserts all pages. Or you can specify specific pages, a range, or `{}` for a blank page

\end{document}
```

Note that `\cleardoublepage` only inserts a blank page with classes that are made for two sided printing (eg. book)

More options and info on `pdfpages` can be found on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

Comment: To include all pages automatically, you can use `\includepdf[pages=-]{...}`.

Comment: @jofel Thanks, fixed the question. I think it defaults to all pages too, I just put it in there to show that it was possible to select certain pages.

Comment: @jofel Also, `\cleardoublepage` only inserts a blank page if you're using a class made for two sided printing. I was using article which doesn't work; I fixed it and updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: `\includepdf` includes only the first page by default (not all pages). `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` works also.

Comment: From what i see i'd have to explicitely write all files that have to be included, so that's not good enough for me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was under the impression that you were doing that anyways (listing them all in command line args). While you could automate this with LaTeX easily enough, the python example is a better way of doing it anyhow, so I'll leave this as is.

Answer (score 1):

[Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66455/32950) worked for me, but since i have to merge many files it's more convenient if i can read their names from a text file.  I've slightly modified Gilles' code to do just that, maybe it would help someone else:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# requires PyPdf library, version 1.13 or above -
# its homepage is http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/
# running: ./this-script-name file-with-pdf-list > output.pdf

import copy, sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
output = PdfFileWriter()
output_page_number = 0

# every new file should start on (n*alignment + 1)th page
# (with value 2 this means starting always on an odd page)
alignment = 2

listoffiles = open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines()
for filename in listoffiles:
    # This code is executed for every file in turn
    input = PdfFileReader(open(filename))
    for p in [input.getPage(i) for i in range(0,input.getNumPages())]:
        # This code is executed for every input page in turn
        output.addPage(p)
        output_page_number += 1
    while output_page_number % alignment != 0:
        output.addBlankPage()
        output_page_number += 1
output.write(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with PyPDF2 and python3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


# requires PyPdf2 library, version 1.26 or above -
# its homepage is https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/index.html
# running: ./this-script-name output.pdf file-with-pdf-list

import copy, sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
output = PdfFileWriter()
output_page_number = 0

# every new file should start on (n*alignment + 1)th page
# (with value 2 this means starting always on an odd page)
alignment = 2

for filename in sys.argv[2:]:
    # This code is executed for every file in turn
    input = PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
    output.appendPagesFromReader(input)
    output_page_number += input.getNumPages()

    while output_page_number % alignment != 0:
        output.addBlankPage()
        output_page_number += 1

output.write(open(sys.argv[1], "wb"))
```